# Q: SenderId is a method and cannot be assigned

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm currently working on a project using [JSQMessageViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) and
an getting an error `required method not implemented: -[JSQMessagesViewController senderId]'` but when I tried assigning a string value to `self.senderId` in `viewDidLoad` it returns an error saying that I can't assign to property: senderId is a method. How should I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `senderId` method in your `JSQMessagesViewController` subclass and return the current sender's unique identifier. See the documentation for `JSQMessagesCollectionViewDataSource` (which `JSQMessagesViewController` conforms to) [here](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/develop/JSQMessagesViewController/Model/JSQMessagesCollectionViewDataSource.h):

```
/**
 *  Asks the data source for the current sender's unique identifier, that is, the
 *  current user who is sending messages.
 *
 *  @return An initialized string identifier that uniquely identifies the current
 *          sender.
 *
 *  @warning You must not return `nil` from this method. This value must be unique.
 */
- (NSString *)senderId;
```

Also, look at [JSQMessagesViewController.m](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/develop/JSQMessagesViewController/Controllers/JSQMessagesViewController.m) and search for `NSAssert` to find all the methods that you need to override in your subclass.

Comment: I've tried overriding the senderId function but got `Method does not override any method from its superclass` can you show me an example of how to do it?

Comment: Does your view controller subclass from `JSQMessagesViewController`? It needs to subclass from that in order for you to override those methods. Here's a Swift example of such a subclass: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/develop/SwiftExample/SwiftExample/ChatViewController.swift

Comment: Yes, exactly the same as the example. Here's what I have:

`import UIKit
import JSQMessagesViewController

class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {
    let sender = "name"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func senderId() -> String {
        return sender
    }
}`